# continuous log file processing and extract required data using python

Tags: python, logging, bigdata

I have to analyze a log file which will generate continuously 24*7. So, the data will be huge. I will have credentials to where log file is generating. But how can I get that streaming data ( I mean like any free tools or processes) so that I can use it in my python code to extract some required information from that log stream and will have to prepare a real time dashboard with that data. please tell some possibilities to achieve above task.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a logger in your python code by importing the following:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', level=logging.DEBUG) # Creates log file
```

From there, you can use the logger to keep track of specific tasks in your program based off of their importance of the task that you wish to perform:

```
logging.info("Stream data recorded successfully")  # Reports events occuring
logging.debug("Running Diagnostics") # Can be used for detailed diagnostic tracking
logging.warning("Unknown File: " + filename) # Issues warnings about runtime events
logging.error("An issue occurred") # reports error without raising an exception
```

After all of that data is collected, you can parse the logs to find the specific messages that you would like to use in the real time dashboard (parse for only errors and warnings for example), without having to display every single message that was sent to the logger. That being said, there is a [log parser library package](https://pypi.org/project/pylogsparser/) available for python that can be easily installed using pip:

```
pip install pylogsparser
```

If you would rather parse manually via python code, this file from [Code Hanger](https://codehangar.io/smiple-log-and-file-processing-in-python/) is useful to get started and modify based on your specific project.

There is also much more information about logger on [python's documentation website](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html), and here is a [basic logging tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) to help you get started. I hope this explanation helped you get started.

Comment: Hi, the log file generated is not related to my application. The log file belongs to another application. I just have to get that log data to my python code continuously and apply some analytics. But how will I get that continuous or streaming log data of another application to my code. Is there any tool I can use? because it is a big data.

Comment: I would reccomend looking into FileHandler, and further into StreamHandler or SocketHandler since you are dealing with another application's files
 https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like pygtail will do what you want:
https://pypi.org/project/pygtail/

```
from pygtail import Pygtail

for line in Pygtail("some.log"):
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion

You could try with ELK:

ELK, short for Elasticsearch (ES), Logstash, and Kibana, is the most popular open source log aggregation tool. Es is a NoSQL. Logstash is a log pipeline system that can ingest data, transform it, and load it into a store like Elasticsearch. Kibana is a visualization layer on top of Elasticsearch.

or

you could use Mongo DB to handle such huge amount of data:

MongoDB is an open-source document database and leading NoSQL. Mongo DB stores data in a json format. Process the logs and store it in a json format and retrieve it for any further use.

Basically its not a simple question to explain, it depends on the scenarios.